# How could I protect an Google Maps Key in an Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I am writing an angular2 app that interacts with Google Maps, and I need to store in the angular app the developer key that google maps give me to me. Since the angular2 apps run on the browser, I would like to ask If what should be the best way to use google maps on angular2 apps and be careful with the security of the developer google maps api key?

Comment: In the developer console you can limit the key to certain domains so the key is only usable on www.foo.bar for example.

Answer (score 2):

Everything on client side is, in a way, available to the end user.
Have you registered the authorized URLs on the Google Maps console ? So if an unknown origin try to load the library using your key, it'll be refused by Google.